# can we use encryption at creation of table

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    PersonId INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,Name VARCHAR(100)
   ,Password VARCHAR(6) 
);
```

how to encrypt password

Comment: Generally, you encrypt it before to put it into the database (more likely you want to salt/hash it, not really encrypt), and decrypt it (again probably just verifying the salted hash, not decrypting) when you pull the data out.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Also the type of your field `password` is way off. `varchar(6)` is way too small

Comment: You want to retrieve the password in decrypted form? If so then the encryption makes no sense. Store not encrypted password but its hash. And when you need to verify entered password then you hash user's input and compare with the hash stored in the table.